# How to remove image from local directories using php

Tags: php, forms, image

I am trying to delete images from local folder of my computer using php and form method. My html form is as follows:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete Image" name="dlt">
</form>
```

and my php code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['dlt'])) {
  if(file_exists("F:\xampp\htdocs\practice\images/".$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $src_file_name = "F:\xampp\htdocs\practice\images/".$_POST['file'];
    unlink($src_file_name);
    echo '<script>alert("File deleted");</script>';
  }
  else {
    echo"<script>alert('File Doesn't exist);</script>";
  }
 }
```

where is the mistake ?

Comment: How should we know - can you explain what exactly is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that the spliced path is correct, and it is recommended that you use the full path, such as "c:\xxx\images\filename". If the problem cannot be resolved, you are advised to provide error information.

Answer (score 0):

First check if function is called in the same directory where is kept "images" directory because if not - it can not find proper folder. It may be that You are calling PHP function from different location than it is defined and it takes location of the folder in which it is called so it may be path problem.

Also I would recommend to put 'die();' right after unlink() because the website will 'die' and unlink() will echo the error it encounters while trying to unlink the file.